# Displaying key and values of the options in a dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, key-value

```js
function keyy(id)
 {
   var value;
var selected;
         var select = document.getElementById(id);
         
                 if(value != null)
                        select.options[selected].text = value; 
         selected = select.selectedIndex;
         var key;
         key =select.options[selected].value;
         value= select.options[selected].text;
         select.options[selected].innerHTML = key; 
 }
```

```html
<select id="Carss" name="Cars" onchange="keyy(this.id)" >
   <option value="A">Audi</option>
   <option value="M">Mercedes</option>
   </select>
```

I have n dropdown values. When I select one value, the corresponding key should be displayed. The drop down should be the values and the display item shoud be the coresponding key.

Have atached the image for the reference.

**My code :**

```
var value;
var selected;
function keyy(id) {
     var select = document.getElementById(id);
     if(value != null)
         select.options[selected].text = value; 
     selected = select.selectedIndex;
     var key;
     key =select.options[selected].value;
     value= select.options[selected].text;
     select.options[selected].text = key; 
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. `<option>`s of `<select>` have display values (element content) and data values (`value` attribute content) so that you can display readable values to the user while using different values internally. I cannot imagine, what purpose could be served by confusing the two. Also, you cannot attach images directly until you achieve adequate reputation.

Comment: Can you show the html mark-up so that maybe we will understand more of what you're trying to do? Is this function triggered by an event? Why do you assign the selectedIndex? Why do you set the value to have the same content of the key? To display the key why don't you use: document.getElementById("show").innerHTML= select.options[selected].value; ?

Comment: @hon2a This function will be triggered as a onchange event of a dropdown. Let me quote an example .                                       Option  Key                                                                   Audi     A                                                                Mercedes M                                                              Initially the options Audi and Mercedes will be displayed . When I click on Audi the key A should be displayed in dropdown which is iam able to achieve from the above code.

Comment: Continued ...   When i click the dropdown for 2nd time the both audi and mercedes should be displayed in dropdown along with the key A in the display item . I have images to clearly tell whats my requirement. But im not able to post images :(

Comment: @softwareplay Please help me with this

Comment: @hon2a  Please help me with this

Comment: If you're not able to link to images and/or CodePen code sample, you can re-create the the problem right here using the "code snippet" tool.

Comment: @hon2a : have added the code snippet . pls check it . when i 1st click on Mercedes, M (key of mercedes) gets displayed which is correct . When i again click on the dropdown M is displayed in the display item and in dropdown. i want Mercedes to be displayed in dropdown and M in display item

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is impossible (with a native `<select>`). The item you see in the closed `<select>` is simply the `<option>` that is currently selected. When you open the drop-down, you see the same `<option>` in two places - in the "selection" and in the "list". You cannot see a different value in each of the places, when it's the same `<option>`.

You could, however, show the selected *value* somewhere else, e.g. in a second element next to the `<select>`.

Comment: Can't I use InnerHTML to display the key and value in the same dropdown ? are there any other techniques i could follow to implement this one?

Comment: `innerHTML` is just the content of that `<option>`. Same `<option>` means same `innerHTML`. If you want to show both the letter and the name as the display value, you can simply do something like `<option value="M">M: Mercedes</option>`.

Comment: As a side note, you haven't really told us why you want this counter-intuitive functionality. When a user selects a value in the drop-down list, she expects that value to show as selected in the box, not some other incomprehensible value.

Comment: I need this functionality to be implemented in the application i work in . I need M to be displayed in the box while in the list i want Mercedes to be displayed when i click it for the 2nd time after selecting a option . Dont want both to be displayed in same line as yu mentioned

Comment: Then you need to implement something more complicated. Like an element that is displayed over the `<select>` content, showing the selected `key`, that is not clickable (`pointer-events: none`), so that clicks on it correctly open the `<select>`.

Comment: I could, or you could read [the pointer-events documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect answer..
But a possible work around..

```js
function key() {
  document.getElementById("Carss").style.width = "100px"
}

function key2() {
  document.getElementById("Carss").style.width = "34px"
  document.getElementById("Carss").blur();
}
```

```html
<select id="Carss" name="Cars" onfocus="key()" onchange="key2()" style="width:34px">
  <option value="A">Audi</option>
  <option value="M">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ! But when i click on the dropdown for 2nd time the key and value of the option selected previously should be displayed . only the values are displayed twice in your code .